# How do I make multilangual content synchronization between two sites?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, feeds

I'm trying to figure out how to synchronize content between 2 sites. Before migration to D8 I was using views data export on site1, and feeds import on site2. My problem is, that in D8 I'm not able to create view where on one row will be English and French content - they can be only two separated rows. But this way I don't know how to set up feeds, to consider these 2 lines as translations of 1 node.

Answer (score 1):

**On the source site:**

1. Make sure that your view has a column that contains an unique identifier for the item. This value must be the same for every language of the item.
2. Add a column to the view that contains the language code. For English this would be 'en' and for French this would be 'fr'.

**On the target site:**

3. On the feed type, map the unique identifier either to:

   - A non-translatable field;
   - Feeds item: GUID.

   And mark that as unique on the feed type.
4. Map to all the fields that you want to map to.
5. Map the langcode value to the "Language" target.

#### Known issues

Note that there are some known issues with importing multilingual content using Feeds. I'm doing my best to resolve them.

You can currently run into the following errors:

- *this field cannot hold more than 1 values.*

  Patch available at https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/3155046
- *A translation already exists for the specified language*

  https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/3126351

  No patch yet, but you could help by confirming or correcting the steps to reproduce the issue.
- *Column cannot be null (SQL error)*

  https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/3169398

  You can help by describing the exact steps to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I have simple csv file `ID,langcode,Title
1738,en,"EN title"
1738,fr,"FR title"`, in feed settings I have mapping id -> field_original_nid (non-translateable, unique), langcode -> Language (langocde), Title -> Title. But on import I've got for both Title and field_original_nid: this field cannot hold more than 1 values. Patch #17 from 3155046 has been applied